# Best way to debug yield return that is consumed during serialization?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, serialization

I'm working on an application that embeds JSON within the page. Some simplified example:

```
public ViewResult Page(IEnumerable<LolCat> lolCats)
{
    var json = new
    {
        localCats = ToJson(lolCats),
    };

    return View( json ); // this gets serialized somewhere in the ASP pipeline
}

IEnumerable<object> ToJson(IEnumerable<LolCat> lolCats)
{
    foreach ( var lolCat in lolCats )
        yield return new { name = lolCat.name };
}
```

The JSON *gets automatically serialized* somewhere down the line in the ASP.NET pipeline.

In this example assume that sometimes a `NULL` slips into `lolCats`, throwing an exception. Problem is that the `ToJson` function might be called at a lot of different places throughout the application.

**How do I find out which call to ToJson was the one responsible for the exception?** The call stack ends in the Serializer that is actually consuming this IEnumerable, and therefore you don't see the **'original stacktrace'**.

[image: The call stack ends in the Serializer that is actually consuming this IEnumerable, and therefore that's not working]

One simple fix would be to call `ToList()` within `Page`. But I'm looking for a way that doesn't break the laziness of the method.

Comment: Nope :) sorry, mocked up some example. I'll fix it! Thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong with `return lolCats.Select(lolCat => new {name=lolCat.name});` then? It would be deferred execution as well.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should've made my question a bit more clear. The real world example is a lot deeper. I'm looking for a way to work in these cases - not a one really specific example to fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the deferred nature, you will never get which call to `ToJson()` actually produced the exception. The collection was never inspected in the first place until it was first enumerated (when it was serialized).

You need to inject into your enumerator some info about what called it.

e.g.,

```
IEnumerable<object> ToJson(IEnumerable<LolCat> lolCats, string id)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var lolCat in lolCats)
            yield return new { name = lolCat.name };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(id, ex); // use a more appropriate exception
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of generating an `id` that could help identify the caller.

Comment: Hi Jeff Mercado, thanks for your answer! I was hoping that there was some solution that was less obtrusive - maybe something similar that would happening within the debugger :) but most likely that is false hope than.